# PHP dns_get_record missing records for subdomains

Tags: php, dns

I'm trying to get a complete list of DNS records associated with a domain, in PHP, if that's possible.

I have been searching for a while, and most of the answers to related questions show code like this:

```
$result = dns_get_record("php.net",DNS_ALL);
print_r($result);
```

However, when I use that code to check one of my domains, there are a lot of records missing. No records are shown at all for subdomains.

It is possible to get a complete list of DNS records for a domain along with the records for any subdomains, in PHP, without knowing ahead of time what those subdomains are?

Comment: Wrote this: http://yrmailfrom.me/tools/dns/adv_dns.php to do that. You won't get all the records. I ended up using PEAR Net_DNS2 and looping over the record types and sub-domains I want. The only way to truly get all the records is to request a Zone Transfer. Not happening with most public DNS Servers. I will post my code as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted, I would suggest using Pear Net DNS2. Here is a thorough example: http://pastebin.com/bAriPVN9

When you do a lookup, I prefer to check against Google Public DNS (8.8.8.8), but you may have another preference. Here is an example of how you can set that:

```
<?php
if($_GET['showData']){
        echo "Posted: <pre>";
        print_r($_GET);
        echo "</pre>\n";
}

$host = trim($_GET['host']);
require_once 'Net/DNS2.php';

switch($_GET['ns']){
        case "google":
                $ns = array('8.8.8.8');
                break;
        default:
                if(isset($_GET['other'])){
                        $ns = array($_GET['other']);
                } else {
                        $ns = array($_GET['ns']);
                }
                break;
}
```

My original code was being setup to work like an API. Users could make a GET or POST request and get Result Records in different ways. This project did not go in that direction, yet you will see some extra steps in the code toward that. Next you want to set or pick the Record Types you're going to want to lookup.

```
if(empty($_GET['r'])){
        // Set Default Record Types to lookup
        $_GET['r'] = array('A', 'MX', 'SRV', 'TXT', 'CNAME', 'NS');
}
```

I wanted A Records, Mail Exchange Records, Service Records, Text, Conical Records, and Name Server Records. I never tested with lower case, but had no interest in finding out if either worked.

I then went through and picked all the Sub-domains I wanted to lookup. Since I was potentially working with different Name Servers, I didn't want to leave it to chance. If you ask for ALL or *, the NS may ignore the request. Ask for a specific record, it will always give you a response.

```
if(empty($_GET['s'])){
        // Set Default Dub-Domains to lookup
        $_GET['s']['a'] = array('root', 'ftp', 'list', 'mail', 'store', 'www');
        $_GET['s']['m'] = array('list');
        $_GET['s']['c'] = array('autodiscover');
        $_GET['s']['s'] = array('_sip._tls', '_sipfederationtls._tcp');
}
```

Now we can start iterating all this and collecting the results. Results can come back in different ways depending on the type of record or the Resource Data elements. Also if the lookup fails, maybe the record does not exist, we have to handle that. Hence the `try{} catch()` blocks.

I don't actually lookup a sub-domain called 'root'. I used this as a placeholder for the 2nd level: `php.net` versus the 3rd level domains: `www.php.net`.

```
$record_results = array();

foreach($_GET['r'] as $record){
        // A Records
        if($record == "A"){
                if($_GET['s']['a'][0] == "root"){
                        if($_GET['showData']){
                                echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>Performing A Record lookup on $host</td></tr>\r\n";
                        }
                        try {
                                $result = $r->query($host, 'A');
                        } catch(Net_DNS2_Exception $e) {
                                //echo "::query() failed: ", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                                if(!$suppressNoData){
                                        printf("\t<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%d</td></tr>\n", $host, "A", "No Data", 0);
                                }
                                continue;
                        }

                        //
                        // loop through the answer, printing out the A records returned.
                        //
                        foreach($result->answer as $arr) {
                                $data = $arr->address;
                                printf("\t<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%d</td></tr>\n", $arr->name, $arr->type, $data, $arr->ttl);
                                $record_results[] = array(
                                        'domain' => $arr->name,
                                        'type' => $arr->type,
                                        'data' => $arr->address,
                                        'ttl' => $arr->ttl
                                );
                        }
                        unset($_GET['s']['a'][0]);
                }
```

We then continue through, appending `$sub` on to `$host` for each of the different records we're looking up and collecting the details.

MX And SRV Records can return lots of different data. For example, a domain may have 4 MX Records. So you will get an Array of Objects returned that you have to sift through. I think I copy/pasted that code block twice by accident.

Sure, it may be more effort yet you get the right results. I hope this helps get you going.

Comment: I didn't forget about this question. I just haven't had time to test your code. If it works, it will do what I need, and I'll mark your answer as the excepted one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There were some errors in the Pastebin code, but when I corrected them this script worked fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I had not had a chance to test the code I shared. I had to extract it from a working project and weed out some private details.